# Remove empty paragraphs when Word text pasted ckEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using the latest version of ckEditor. It is used on many pages and people generally paste Word documents into the editor. Word documents tend to be full of empty paragraphs - as that is how many people put spacing between paragraphs. In ckEditor this gets pasted as:

```
<p style="margin-left:0cm; margin-right:0cm>&nbsp;</p>
```

As html tends to have larger paragraph spacing anyway, this extra blank paragraph tag causes a big gap between paragraphs.

I need to call a function when data is pasted into the ckEditor box that will remove these empty paragraphs. Can anyone tell me how to do that please.